# Not able to place a marker on current location in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am new android and i am trying to place a marker on my current location and i have written a code it opens the google map but donot place any marker on my current location.Please help me and thanks in advance 
here is the code of my java file.

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
      android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
      android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {

                Location myLocation  = mMap.getMyLocation();
                if(myLocation!=null)
                {
                    double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
                    double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
                    Log.i("APPLICATION"," : "+dLatitude);
                    Log.i("APPLICATION", " : " + dLongitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
             LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude)).title("Marker"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new 
              LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

                }
                else
                {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to fetch the current  
               location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you called `mapView.getMapAsync(this)` or anything similar to start the map? Adding the marker should be in the overridden function `onMapReady(GoogleMap map)`

Comment: Why don't you put all your `if (mMap != null) {` logic inside of the callback of `getMap()`?

Comment: Are you getting the latitude and longitude printed in Logcat? If not then your code does not gets executed in that block. Put a series of logs at different places to check (mMAP is null etc)

Comment: No i havenot called  mapView.getMapAsync(this)

Comment: And i am not getting latitude or longitude in my logcat

Comment: I believe `getMap()` is deprecated, so `getMapAsync(context)` is the substitute. If you're using fragment in your XML, assign it to a class variable MapFragment and call `getMapAsync` on it, then implement the methods (including `onMapReady()`). If you're using `MapView`, use the `getMapAync` on it after assigning it to a MapView variable

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the longitude and latitude:

```
GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
Float latitude  = new Float(0.0);
Float longitude = new Float(0.0);
if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()) {
  latitude  = gpsTracker.latitude;
  longitude = gpsTracker.longitude;
} else {
  // can't get location
  // GPS or Network is not enabled
  // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
  gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
}
```

You need to call `getMapAsync` on your `MapView` (if in fragment) or `MapFragment` (if in activity), that's according to your structure

```
mapView.getMapAsync(this);

mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: hey..i didnot get you were should i place that gps tracker code while placing onCreate() its not working

Comment: anywhere after `setContent`